# How to find highest velocity and largest displacement a particle can undergo

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

I have a question concerning kinematics of a particle. Let us say that we are given an equation for acceleration in terms of vertical displacement y for a particle. You are then asked to find two things:the largest displacement that the particle can undergo and the highest velocity it can undergo. How do you do so? I was told that to find the velocity I must equate the formula for acceleration equal to zero, solve for y, and then input that value of y in the equation for velocity. As for the displacement, I was told to equate the formula for velocity equal to zero and afterwards solve for y. Is this correct?

If by chance this is a duplicate question, and is tagged as such, please post the link before closing the question query. I tried searching for duplicates beforehand but I couldn't find any.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic)

Comment: Thank you for answering and not keeping silent. Other stack exchanges just write you off without so much as an explanation @ZeroTheHero . That being said, I am just asking as to why velocity's highest magnitude occurs when acceleration is zero and why the longest distance a particle can travel is found when the velocity is zero. Is that not a conceptual question? Or was my wording too close to what is considered a homework question?

Comment: What you describe only makes sense in some circumstances e.g. if the object is undergoing simple harmonic motion and the acceleration is given by something like $d^2y/dt^2 = -ky$. Is this the case in the problem you are considering here?

Comment: @JohnRennie yes, it is. What I want to know, in the cases that this does apply, why is it so.

Comment: OK, I have to dash out now. If no-one has answered when I get back I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of simple harmonic motion, you will reach the maximum velocity when you have stopped accelerating (and acceleration changes sign after that) - because when acceleration changes sign, your velocity will decrease.

Another way of thinking about this: any time a function reaches a maximum, the derivative of that function is zero. And the derivative of velocity (with respect to time) is acceleration. Of course that's "necessary but not sufficient": for a maximum, the second derivative must be negative.

The same approach holds for position: maximum position requires derivative of position with respect to time (i.e. velocity) to be zero.